# HTML levels in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, chrome

In Google Chrome Developer Tools we have an elements tab where we can browse all the elements. However, we don't see the full tree at ones.

Therefor I've build a simple tool for that https://github.com/jenstornell/html-levels.js But then I thought, someone has to have made a better tool than mine.

- **Better colors** - One color for class, one for ids, one for data attributes etc.
- **Skip attributes** - Skip showing of data attributes, or classes etc.

But overall, a tool that does the same thing, but with more time spent on it.

[image]